# Cannot install ArchLinux on Acer Aspire containing windows 8

Tags: windows-8, boot, arch-linux, acer-aspire

I am in a tad bit of a problem . I am trying to install ArchLinux on my new Acer Aspire V5
https://i.stack.imgur.com/buEOM.jpg . I have made my OS usb bootable using software from pendriveinux.com . I have used their software in the past and had success in installing Archlinux in my old laptop also from Acer . My last laptop was 3 years old .

After inserting the usb , I can see the bootup screen, where I get to choose from 64 bit and 32 bit architecture . On clicking any one of the options , I am greeting a screen that says that the kernel loading . However , after that the screen goes blank even though the laptop is on.

Someone in the Archlinux community on Google Plus said that there is a problem with secure booting , that is enabled on uefi mode . But as I fa as I know my laptop runs on legacy bootloader and there is no problem with secure booting .

Anybody came across this problem before ?

Comment: If it was sold with Windows 8 preinstalled, then it's 99.9% likely that you have UEFI.  (Windows stores your key there, oddly enough).  But that being said, you aren't likely booting in any legacy mode and secure boot likely needs to be disabled.

Comment: Does it work if you hit 'E' at the grub menu and add `nomodeset` to the kernel options?

Comment: This is the video http://youtu.be/D6jkqaztkTM and @terdon , how do I do what you have just said ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a UEFI issue, this solution will not work. However, the black screen at boot is a classic problem and it is often solved by modifying the kernel parameters in GRUB. The most common solution is adding the `nomodeset` option (instructions adapted from [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Kernel_parameters#GRUB)):

1. When the GRUB menu shows up press <kbd>E</kbd>
2. That should bring up the GRUB parameters. Navigate to the line beginning with `linux`, it should look something like this:

   ```
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81 quiet splash
   ```

   Remove the `quiet` and `splash` (that makes messages appear that could be helpful if this does not work) and add `nomodeset` so that it looks like this:

   ```
   linux /boot/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=978e3e81 nomodeset
   ```
3. Press <kbd>B</kbd> to boot with these changes.

Let me know if this fixes it. Also, search google for `linux black screen boot` or similar. you will find many many hits about this type of problem.

Useful links:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/
- http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: I am using syslinux bootloader , I hope your instructions are the same here as well .